# Can you work on your own Mechanical Turk task without getting paid (and without paying Amazon)?

Tags: mechanicalturk

Is it possible to work on your own Mechanical Turk task without getting paid, and thus without paying Amazon (to avoid the ~20% fee) ? I would like to crowdsource my task while still being able to work on it in my free time.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can deploy a copy of your project to [Amazon Mechanical Turk Developer Sandbox](https://requestersandbox.mturk.com), and work on it at [Worker Sandbox](https://workersandbox.mturk.com) for free.

However, you do need to pay attention to the guidelines and policies of these sandbox sites. The only banned actions I can find so far are:

> Load or performance testing your MTurk application using the MTurk Developer Sandbox is not allowed. If you have a special need, please contact us here to specify your special circumstance. You will be contacted by a member of our team to discuss your requirements.

Therefore, I assume that as long as you don't spam the sandbox sites with bots or a large number of workers, it should be fine to work on your own project personally.

You might still need to confirm with [MTurk Support](https://www.mturk.com/contact-us) though.